# installing shogun-toolbox in windows

Tags: matlab, installation, shogun

Did anyone install shogun-toolbox successfully in windows 7.
I am getting this Error: could not find matlab developer files (e.g. mex.h)
I am using cygwin, matlab-7.7 and shogun 2.1

Can anyone write the procedure to install it.

pradeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation, it is not possible.

"In addition neither R and matlab interfaces do currently compile" (FAQ / Version 2.0.1)

I suggest to use a VM.

Answer (score 0):

just a quick heads up, I've created an almost complete windows port of shogun and it's available here: https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/tree/feature/windows